How to remove headers like Authorization while using playwright apiContext

My project implemented the Authorization as a fixture so that all test modules can work as a logged-in user.

There is a function to upload a file to s3, which actually consists of a few steps:



initiate upload. It will return the s3 upload_url and something else.
upload to s3. It will use the upload_url and disallow Authorization.

Error message:
InvalidArgumentOnly one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified
I tried to set the headers to empty in my function, but it doesn't work. Can anyone please help me? Do I must add the browserContext and use the route() function?
export const demandTags = async (
  apiContext,
  campaign,
  campaignLinesDetails: CampaignLineResponse[],
  demandTagsDetails: DemandTagRequest[],
  use: (r: DemandTagResponse[]) => Promise<void>,
) => {
  const results: DemandTagResponse[] = [];

  // Get uploadCreative.mp4 from the files
  const filePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readFile('./uploadItems/uploadCreative.mp4', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const file: any = await filePromise;

  // Initiate upload
  const initiateUpload = await apiContext.post('/api/demandtag/initiate_upload/', {
    data: {
      file_name: 'uploadCreative.mp4',
      file_type: 'video/mp4',
      file_size: file.length,
    } as apiTypes.UploadRequest,
  });
  await expect(initiateUpload).toBeOK();

  const responseJSONinitiateUpload = await initiateUpload.json();
  expect(responseJSONinitiateUpload.parts[0].offset).toBe(0);
  expect(responseJSONinitiateUpload.parts[0].limit).toBe(file.length);
  expect(responseJSONinitiateUpload.parts).toHaveLength(1);

  // Upload the part
  const partResponse = await apiContext.put(responseJSONinitiateUpload.parts[0].url, {
    headers: {
      // 'Content-Type': '',
    },
    data: file,
  });
  await expect(partResponse).toBeOK();

  const etag = await partResponse.headers()['etag'];
  const completeUpload = await apiContext.post('/api/demandtag/complete_upload/', {
    data: {
      upload_token: responseJSONinitiateUpload.upload_token,
      etags: [etag],
    } as apiTypes.CompleteUploadRequest,
  });
  await expect(completeUpload).toBeOK();

  const responseJSONcompleteUpload = await completeUpload.json();

  // Create demand tag
  for (const demandTagDetails of demandTagsDetails) {
    const createDemandTag = await apiContext.post('/api/demandtag/', {
      data: {
        name: demandTagDetails.name,
        budget_value: demandTagDetails.budgetValue,
        campaign_line: campaignLinesDetails[0].id,
        pixel_url: demandTagDetails.pixelUrl,
        creative_landing_page_url: demandTagDetails.creativeLandingPageUrl,
        creative_s3: responseJSONcompleteUpload.url,
        creative_slug: demandTagDetails.creativeSlug,
        start_date: demandTagDetails.startDate,
        end_date: demandTagDetails.endDate,
      } as apiTypes.DemandTagRequest,
    });

    await expect(createDemandTag).toBeOK();
    results.push({ ...demandTagDetails, id: (await createDemandTag.json()).id });
  }

  await use(results);

  // Delete created demand tags
  for (const demandTag of results) {
    const responseDelete = await apiContext.delete(`/api/demandtag/${demandTag.id}/`);
    expect([204, 404]).toContain(responseDelete.status());
  }
};

The fixture defined in another file:
export const test = base.extend<TestFixtures, WorkerFixtures>({
  authToken: async ({ request }, use) => {
    await authToken(request, use);
  },
  apiContext: async ({ authToken }, use) => {
    await use(
      await request.newContext({
        baseURL: `${process.env.PROTOCOL!}://${process.env.HOST!}:${process.env.PORT!}`,
        extraHTTPHeaders: {
          authorization: `Token ${authToken}`,
        },
      }),
    );
  },
  staticUrl: [
    async ({}, use) => {
      await staticUrlFixture(use);
    },
    { scope: 'worker' },
  ],
});



There's very little code here. Please share a [mcve]--enough code that we can run and see the problem. See Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?. Thanks.

Thanks for your comment. I've updated the whole function code and the fixture defined in another file.

Thanks, getting closer but still not reproducible. I can't run this to see the problem.
